# How to display single row out from a repeating set based upon a condition?

Tags: sql

```
acquisitionID    Logno.             FundName
1               2                   Allocated
1               2                   Potential
2              34                   Allocated
3              37                   Potential
4              40                   Allocated
4              40                   Potential
5              39                   Potential
```

I want to display only those rows which have  FundName as Allocated if there are two funds to it i.e.(Allocated/Potential) otherwise I want to display it as it is. i.e.

```
acquisitionID   Logno.               FundName
1               2                   Allocated
2               34                  Allocated
3               37                  Potential
4               40                  Allocated
5               39                  Potential
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AcquisitionID, [LogNo.], min(FundName)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY AcquisitionID, [LogNo.]
```

Comment: All the values in the first table are generated after joining other tables so I want something which helps me in a way that if there is already a row present with a given AcquisitionID then it shouldn't be picking up any other row with the sameid.